# Start computations automatically only after view has appeared

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have a view controller that just shows progress during calculations. I put the method calls

in `viewDidLoad` but the problem is the view only appears once the calculations are done! How

could I automatically launch the calculations after the view has appeared on screen?

Comment: thread the calculations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). Here is [Raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        //Calculations
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Update UI must be here
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call the superclass implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad:` triggers when the view is loaded.  This is different from when the view is displayed.

Try starting the calculations in the `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` callback method on  `UIViewController` instead.

---

If these calculations take a while, considering running them on a background thread.  This will prevent the UI from locking up while the calculations are running.  This has the bonus of not only allowing the view to show, but it can be interacted with while the user waits.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doCalc)
                       withObject:nil];
```

From that `doCalc` method you would call back to the main thread with the result.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didCalcValue:)
                       withObject:result
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have correctly pointed out, `viewDidAppear` let's you know when the view has appeared on screen. *Also, don't forget to call `super` when you use these event methods.

**Example:**

```
// Tells the view controller that its view was added to the view hierarchy.

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  // makes sure it's also called on the superclass
  // because your superclass may have it's own code
  // needing to be called here
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  // do your calculations here

}
```

**Commonly used UIViewController events:**

```
– (void)viewDidLoad
```

Called when your view first loads in memory.

```
– (void)viewDidAppear:
```

Called after your view has appeared on screen.

```
– (void)viewWillDisappear:
```

Called before your view will disappear from the screen.

See the full list on the [UIViewController Class Reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).